# Can't Verify Contract on etherscan.io or etherchain.org

Tags: mist, etherscan, verify

I've deployed a contract, which I generated using Mist but I can't seem to get it to verify.

At [etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/verifyContract) I keep getting the error:

> > Error! Invalid constructor arguements provided. Please verify that they are correctly ABI-encoded

[I'm really growing to hate that 'arguements' typo!]

even though I'm copying the ABI directly from Mist [and 
I've checked I'm using the correct compiler version].

I've also tried verifying on [etherchain.org](https://etherchain.org/account_verify) but that does bugger all. I just get the text on the submit button changing to `Verifying...` but nothing happens.

None of the above is helped by the fact that I'm not entirely sure, when either of these sites asks me to paste in the 'contract code', whether they're looking for the original Javascript version or the complied bytecode version. although I've tried pretty much every combo I can think of.

Anyone got either of these sites to verify a contract?... and, if so, could you provide an idiot's guide to how you did it?

[I didn't think I was an idiot 'til I tried expanding my cryptocurrency interests into Ethereum but it's been like pulling teeth getting any of the software to work properly!]

Comment: Possibly related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10431/having-trouble-verifying-a-contract-on-etherscan-io

Comment: Do you have a gist of your contract code, solc version, optimizer setting and contract address which you are trying to verify? Ps: I've fixed the "arguements" typo on Etherscan